# Calling parameterised constructor using compiled expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression-trees

I'm trying to create a compiled expression delegate to call a constructor taking a single parameter, I'm receiving the following exception:

```
Additional information: variable 'value' of type 'MyType' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

The code is as follows:

```
var constructorInfo = instanceType.GetConstructors().Skip(1).First();

ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(genericArgument, "value");
Delegate constructorDelegate = Expression.Lambda(Expression.New(constructorInfo, new Expression[] { param })).Compile();
```

I believe I'm receving the exception because the parameter 'value' is not scoped inside an Expression.Block.

How do I scope the parameter & constructor expressions inside an Expression.Block?

Comment: Could you post type definition with ctor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to declare the parameter `value`, you need to also specify it when creating the Lambda expression (see this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343032%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the Expression.Lambda method). Up to now, you only create a parameterized lambda expression, but do not declare the parameters that are used in the expression. Changing your code should solve the issue:

```
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.New(constructorInfo, 
                                                  new Expression[] { param }), 
                                   param);
Delegate constructorDelegate = lambdaExpr.Compile();
```

Comment: this didn't quite work, I've posted the answer below

Comment: @AwkwardCoder: good to hear that it works now. However, I can't see the difference to my answer. The relevant change seems to be to add `param` to the call of `Expression.Lambda` as an extra parameter. Anyway, if it works, it works.

Comment: @AwkwardCoder: Thanks for double-checking - I really didn't understand the difference as I've also checked my solution before and couldn't identify a relevant difference. Have a great day!